# Accessing returned parameter by python method

Tags: python, oop, variables, scope

My code looks something like

```
Class Some_class():

    def _functionA():
         # body
        return parameterA, parameterB

    def second_function():
         var1 = parameterB
```

How can I access parameterB, returned by the first function into the second?

Comment: Well in that case a **tuple** is returned, so you can access it with `return_value[1]`.

Comment: You can't unless `second_function` actually intends on calling the first function

Comment: why not, you output parameterB ?

Comment: You've already tagged this question with scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python interprets:

```
return parameterA, parameterB
```

as:

```
return (parameterA, parameterB)
```

so you return a **tuple**. You can access the *i*-th element of a tuple (0-based index), by writing `return_value[1]`. So in you case, it should be something like:

```
def second_function():
    var1 = self._functionA()[1]
```

You can also use *sequence assignment*, for instance:

```
def second_function():
    _,var1 = self._functionA()
```

here you thus write `var,iable = expression`. In the case `expression` is a sequence with length equal to the number of variables, the first element in the sequence is assigned to `var`, the second to `iable`, and so on.